# Animated/ Slide Side-Menu doesn't slide left-ward?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I solve the problem of a Side-Menu that doesn't slide out-and-in from the left (Leftward)? I got it from YouTube Video. Backtrack to the YouTube presenter without feedback.

It consists of  HTML, CSS and JavaScript.

---

### Index File

The Index file is the file invokes or synchronize with CSS file and JavaScript files

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <link href="toggleMenu.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script link="toggleMenu.js"></script>  

</head>

<body>

    <div id="sidebar">
        <div class="toggle-btn" onclick="toggleSidebar()">
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>About</li>
            <li>Contact</li>
        </ul>
    </div> 

</body>
</html>
```

---

### CSS File:

The CSS file defines various class with defined attributes

```
* {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

#sidebar {
    position:fixed;
    width:200px;
    height:100%;
    background:#151719;
    left:-200px;
    transition: all 500ms linear;
}

#sidebar.active{
    left:0px;
}

#sidebar ul li {
    color:rgba(230, 230, 230, 0.9);
    list-style:none;
    padding:15px 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.3);
}

#sidebar .toggle-btn {
    position:absolute;
    left:230px;
    top:20px;
}

#sidebar .toggle-btn span {
    display: block;
    width:30px;
    height:5px;
    background:#151719;
    margin: 5px 0px;
}
```

---

### JavaScript

JavaScript handling the sliding effect when user click on the Toggle Button (toggle-btn)

```
function toggleSidebar() {

    document.getElementByID("sidebar").classlist.toggle("active");

}
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of typos in your toggle function, it should be:

```
function toggleSidebar() {
  document.getElementById("sidebar").classList.toggle("active");
}
```

Here's a working version, click on run snippet below:

```js
function toggleSidebar() {
    document.getElementById("sidebar").classList.toggle("active");
}
```

```css
* {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

#sidebar {
    position:fixed;
    width:200px;
    height:100%;
    background:#151719;
    left:-200px;
    transition: all 500ms linear;
}

#sidebar.active{
    left:0px;
}

#sidebar ul li {
    color:rgba(230, 230, 230, 0.9);
    list-style:none;
    padding:15px 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.3);
}

#sidebar .toggle-btn {
    position:absolute;
    left:230px;
    top:20px;
}

#sidebar .toggle-btn span {
    display: block;
    width:30px;
    height:5px;
    background:#151719;
    margin: 5px 0px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="sidebar">
  <div class="toggle-btn" onclick="toggleSidebar()">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
  </div>
  <ul>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>About</li>
      <li>Contact</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 points you need to fix

script should be using src attributes instead of **link**, so it will be

```
<script src="toggleMenu.js"></script>
```

And the classList should be written with capital L, so instead of `document.getElementById("sidebar").classlist.toggle("active");` it
should be

```
document.getElementById("sidebar").classList.toggle("active");
```

Answer (score 0):

https://codepen.io/divided7/pen/PoPrwPe I made you a codepen, with the fixed result.
Also, change `link` to `src` in your code for the script tag, and the typo (`classlist` to `classList`)

Comment: How can I close this question?